# Bash script to find directories on system contains > 1000 files?

Tags: file, directory, dir

I need a way of finding all the directories on a server that contain more than a set number of files (eg. 1000+).  I work on many big servers, and sometimes find directories containing millions of small log files.  I need a way to find these dirs.

I was thinking something along the lines of scripting a full dir listing and then doing...
ll | wc -l
...but thought there might be a better/quicker way to do it?

I am ideally going to set this script to run in the crontab to run once a week.

Cheers,
Stu

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer:

```
[[ `ls -1 | wc -l` -gt 1000 ]] && echo `pwd`
```

And a cycle around... But without a cycle:

```
 ls -1R|awk -F "\n" 'BEGIN {RS="\\n\\n"} NF>1000 {print $1, NF-1}'
```

**EDIT:**

as `awk` can't handle that large records (over 3000 bytes), I'd go with:

```
for dirz in `find . -type d -print` ; do
    [[ `ls -1 $dirz | wc -l` -gt 1000 ]] && echo $dirz
done
```

HTH

Comment: I tried this, but it just tells me "Input line <snip> cannot be longer than 3,000 bytes." for every server I try it on?

Comment: The 2nd one.  Is it possible to modify the first with ls -1R to get it to do all dirs?

Comment: Yep, in that case awk can not handle that large records (in this case a record is a directory name and all its files).

Comment: Thanks, I worked with your script and it's now as follows...
for dirz in `find / -type d -print` ; do
 [[ `ls -1p $dirz | grep -v \/ | wc -l` -gt 1000 ]] && echo $dirz
done
...however I am now hitting one more slight problem.  If the directory name found contains a space character it gives errors saying 'No such file or directory'.  Is there a way to add wildcards or quotes around the dirz to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do a two stage approach like so (untested):

```
find / -type d -exec sh -c "find {} -depth 1 -type f -print | wc -l" \; | while read F N
  do
     [ $N -gt 1000 ] && echo $F $N
  done
```

Comment: Unless i'm understanding this one wrong, i think it will find/count every file in a directory (AND in its sub dirs)... which is not what i need ideally, as I'm only after a list of dirs that actually contain gt 1000 files themselves (not including sub dirs).

Comment: find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [path...] [expression]

Comment: Well, I guess the inner find must be replaced by a script to get the {} properly substituted.